# No space between text and buttons on tag top users page

Tags: bug, tags, design, localization, responsive-design

There's no space between text and buttons on tag top users page:

> [image]

Related to ruSO, [rusSE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tags/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/topusers).